# MPI (Asynchronous) Loop Iteration

Tags: c, asynchronous, mpi

I have a program similar to the one below. In the code below, all processes know the current iteration step of all other processes. However, I am curious if there is a way to do this without a collective call such as MPI_PUT, **especially in a case where each process iterates at a different rate**.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* OUTPUT
 * $ mpirun -np 4 so00.exe
 * @[0]: p |       0       1       2       3
 * @[0]: p |       4       5       6       7
 * @[0]: p |       8       9       10      11
 * @[0]: p |       12      13      14      15
 * @[0]: p |       16      17      18      19
 * @[1]: p |       0       1       2       3
 * @[1]: p |       4       5       6       7
 * @[1]: p |       8       9       10      11
 * @[1]: p |       12      13      14      15
 * @[1]: p |       16      17      18      19
 * @[2]: p |       0       1       2       3
 * @[2]: p |       4       5       6       7
 * @[2]: p |       8       9       10      11
 * @[2]: p |       12      13      14      15
 * @[2]: p |       16      17      18      19
 * @[3]: p |       0       1       2       3
 * @[3]: p |       4       5       6       7
 * @[3]: p |       8       9       10      11
 * @[3]: p |       12      13      14      15
 * @[3]: p |       16      17      18      19
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, n, rank, np;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    int *pos;
    MPI_Win win;
    MPI_Alloc_mem(sizeof(int)*np, MPI_INFO_NULL, &pos);
    MPI_Win_create(pos, np, sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win);

    for (i=rank; i<(np*5); i+=np)
    {
        MPI_Win_fence(MPI_MODE_NOPRECEDE, win);
        for (n = 0; n < np; n++)
        {
            MPI_Put(&i, 1, MPI_INT, n, rank, 1, MPI_INT, win);
        }
        MPI_Win_fence((MPI_MODE_NOSTORE | MPI_MODE_NOSUCCEED), win);
        printf("@[%d]: p | ", rank);
        for (n = 0; n < np; n++) printf("\t%d", pos[n]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    MPI_Win_free(&win);
    MPI_Free_mem(pos);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: MPI_Put is NOT a collective call.

Comment: Ah, I think I confused that with MPI_Win_fence...

Comment: You cannot avoid MPI_Win_fence before using RMA calls. Its a requirement. You can optimize your code by moving the fence out of the outer for loop. The way it is now, the NOPRECEDE & NOSUCCEED are no appropriate in the current location.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I moved the fences outside the loop and got numbers like: `@[0]: p |       -1698087256     32723   -1698087256     32723   32`. I solved the situation with something like the solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612421/mpi-asynchronous-one-sided-communication. Though, I'm curious if there's is any other way to do it with RMA or other tricks. Thanks again.

Comment: If I put the processes in a separate MPI group, is there a way to modify the window, group, or communicator handle, or all of them, such that, when one completes the loop, it removes itself from the group associated with the window??

Comment: If I am not mistaken, group creation, modification are collective calls. So if you want to remove a rank from a group, every process needs to be involved. Pls check the documentation for group related ops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not required that you use `MPI_Win_fence` to synchronize RMA calls in MPI. It's also possible to use `MPI_Lock` (and its variants) to do what is called "passive target" mode. This mode is much less synchronizing as it doesn't require all of the collective calls that the "active target" mode does.

It's far too complex to provide a full answer here, but you can find many papers about the subject along with the documentation on the web. The full MPI-3 standard is available [here](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf). Take a look at Chapter 11 for one-sided communication.